# What logical fallacies exist in David Lewis and Stephanie Lewis' article called "holes"?

Tags: metaphysics, fallacies, debate, david-lewis

In David & Stephanie Lewis' Article "Holes" the nominalist/realist debate gets taken to a phenomena that all of us are likely directly aware of at one point in our lives.

Holes.

The absent areas of cheese in a block of swiss, the space of an open window, the inside of a paper towel roll, etc. etc.

Argle and Bargle debate if holes are in fact material objects, or the absence of material objects.

At first the debate seems trivial but it quickly gets into the gritty details.

My question is what logical fallacies did Argle and Bargle commit in their debate?

If you have not encountered it before the 7 page article can be read in its entirety here : [Holes](https://books.google.com/books?id=S4t5qNYRTXQC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=argle%20and%20bargle%20holes&source=bl&ots=csOh3P0AeT&sig=_OUQzdhOIq-aSiRBxdowzApPwXc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f4SJVbWhG8OHsAWLnKGgCw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=argle%20and%20bargle%20holes&f=false)

Comment: Note: there is no tag for nominalism, so I put debate instead. Someone should create a nominalism tag.

Comment: There's actually a really good question or two you could construct around that paper and the realist-nominalist debate, but you need to reword it so that you're not asking "who won the debate (in your opinion)" and instead asking something answerable in a philosophy.SE Q&A format. Do you have a specific question from your reading of the article you want help with?

Comment: @virmaior

I honestly cannot believe you closed this.

Comment: @virmaior "rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." The article is linked and quotes are encouraged, this is not an opinion based question, it is encouraging discussion and debate on the article. Is this a philosophy stack or not?

Comment: @virmaior so are you suggusting that the nominalist / realist debate has a definitive answer? If so post that as an answer, because otherwise your claim that this question is based on opinion is completely bogus.

Comment: this is first and foremost a stackexchange, meaning it's a Q&A system where people can ask questions to receive answers. The scope of this stackexchange is philosophy roughly defined around the academic discipline. It is not meant for "discussion and debate" but rather specific answerable questions about philosophy. By your own comments, your question is not seeking an answer but rather "discussion and debate"

Comment: The edit makes it better, but question 1 is still polling for opinions.

Comment: The subject of the question is good; it's as been noted the actual specific question that's a problem for SE.

Comment: @hellyale - http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/474/friends-we-are-not-philosophers .  It can be a little confusing at first, but this is a site *about* philosophy, not *for* philosophy.  Many wonderful philosophy questions are not on topic here, because there is no objective, non-controversial answer that can be given.

Comment: @virmaior any better?

Comment: This is better and good enough to reopen that we can reopen it and see what happens. It's not perfect because you are asking people to "list fallacies" Best, would be if you shared a passage that you think has a problem or that you had trouble with (or an objection to) and articulated a specific problem.

Comment: @virmaior thanks for the feedback and patience. I'll take it all into consideration before posting another question.

Comment: @Chris Sunami what if there was a stack for each main position,  IE Question A has 3 main schools of thought. In this case we could use nominalism as one school, realism as another and so forth. The answers could tag their answer with the school they represent. So then you could see the top answer from each perspective. I'm not sure how choosing answers would work, perhaps a community vote for each school of thought, or the user just picks the one that sways them most, or some other configuration?

Comment: @hellyale "Yes" to your first step, questions referencing one specific school of thought are solidly on topic: We answer those all the time.  The difference there is that we're just elucidating the views of a specified school, not presenting one view as definitive.  "No" on the second step, it's not our job to do original philosophy here or settle ongoing debates.  It's not a perfect system by any means, but I personally find it far more useful and objective than most of the competitors, where subconscious biases often dominate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My answer to the question as stated is: None. Nobody commits a fallacy at any point in the dialogue, as far as I can see. This is utterly unsurprising--a pair of professional philosophers committing a logical fallacy in a published paper would be like a professional basketball player missing a wide open, no-pressure layup. It can happen, but it's really rare.

That doesn't mean that the Lewis' positions are *correct*, It just means that the premises they give in support of their conclusion do in fact support the conclusion. Whether those premises are *actually true* is the important thing, and that is not a matter of logic.

There are no generally effective ways of proving which premises are actually true.

Comment: "Whether those premises are actually true is the important thing, and that is not a matter of logic." Not sure I follow this line of thinking. How is determining the soundness not a matter of logic? If you can use logic to disprove a premise the valid argument rests on are you not using logic to deduce unsoundness?

Comment: @hellyale Logic can not disprove premises unless they imply contradiction, and then you have a choice of which premises to discard. There are plenty of collections of premises that do not result in contradictions, in which case logic has nothing to say about their truth. Sometimes empirical considerations might, and sometimes their truth can not be proved or disproved by any means whatsoever.

Comment: Conifold is correct. Logic is a powerful tool, but it isn't sufficient by itself to tell us what to believe. For that we need science, common sense and sometimes philosophical insight.